# Is there a way to find numbers which is more or less than certain exponent?

Tags: c++, exponent, data-filtering

I have a code writes a robot coordination in a file. Sometimes, for an unknown reason, instead of a number like 0.01845, it writes 6.92113e-310. So I'd like to filter data raised to a power greater than -12. Is there a way to achieve this in C++?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If it's a number, you can compare with `1e-12`, e.g. `auto num = 6.92113e-310; if (num < 1e-12) ...`

Comment: -310 is less than 12. It's even less than zero. `6.92113e-310.` is 0.0000(....)00069, there are 310 zeroes before the 6.

Comment: Round the output to a certain number of digits behind the decimal point. How do you output the data? cout? printf? fmt?

Comment: @MSalters, sorry I made a mistake in question. It's not 12, but -12.

Comment: @Sebastian, I write data as myfile << parsed_data[0] << ";";

Comment: @Edvard: Doesn't really change my point. -310 is also less than -12.

Answer (score -1):

Just to help with the math: you get the exponent using [`std::log10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10).

This actually returns the exponent as the integer part, and the significand (the 6.9113 before the e) controls the fractional part of `log10`.

Filtering a collection by a predicate should be in your C++ textbook.

Comment: Thank you reply. jabaa suggestion has worked great for me.